# iPad books do not show all images

Tags: books

I have an iPad2 (brand new) onto which I have loaded books from the app store. Most of these books are showing a blue question make where the images should be. This includes the 'iPad User Guide" from Apple itself.

In the "iPad User Guide," it also shows the following error message:

This page contains the following errors:
error on Line 1 at column 1: Document is empty error on Line 1 at column 1: Encoding error

On some books, double tapping the icon will display the picture but on others it wont. If I attempt to adjust the font size, the app just crashes.

Has anyone come across this? Is there some magic setting I'm missing?

BTW: PDF books work fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just installed the latest update for iBooks and the problem is fixed.